How to sync / update a folder and down-scale / down-sample files on-the-fly?
Goal
I would like to sync / update all files and folders from a source folder to a target folder with the following additional requirements:

apply a script on certain file types at target when files get updated to reduce their size, i.e. down-scale images/videos, down-sample audio
sync other file types as is
ignore certain file types completely, so they won't appear in the target
avoid redundant processing, so files should only be processed if the target file does not exist or its creation time stamp is older than in the source
on-the-fly processing for each file, so that it is not required to make a full copy of the full data before actually post-processing it (otherwise it would require twice the space temporarily)
support for change of file type, but still treated as "synced" (e.g. *.flac in source, *.mp3 in target)
nice-to-have: add a file name suffix to files processed by the script

Use cases
I would like to create down-scaled/sampled copies of my media libraries (such as photos and music) in a separate folder, keep these updated and sync them to my phone using Syncthing. As phone memory is limited / expensive in my case (no support for external SD cards), I prefer having quality-reduced versions of such media libraries on my phone while maintaining the original quality on my computer.
Questions
I know there are command-line tools, which would allow writing this as a bash script (utilizing ImageMagick/ffmpeg). Before I (or any of you) start writing that, I would like to figure out:

Are there any known solutions to this?
If not, is there any simpler way other than writing a custom bash script?
Are there any existing solutions I can use or combine and if yes how? (e.g. rsync with ImageMagick?)

Update 30.08.2024
Added on-the-fly processing requirement.
I realized the simple case of first rsync fully than post-process using ImageMagick or ffmpeg would acually work using rsync's update flag. I didn't realize that before, so I will add an intermediate solution here once I had time to refine the solution. However, I also realized this would require twice the space of the original data temporarily, which can be a problem for media libraries, so I added a requirement above to support on-the-fly processing for each file.

Please read How do I ask a good question? And stick to one question instead of asking multiple questions.

A novel solution might be to create a
FUSE filesystem that transparently
applies conversions whenever you access a file.
If this is too slow, you could always rsync it to another directory when
there are changes.
There are many fuse filesystems that implement some limited ascpect of
this, but they are mostly written in programming languages like go, python,
C. However, there is the cmdfs fuse
filesystem, that can run a (shell or other) command when you try to read a
file, and does not need you to write code. The first example mentioned in
the man
page
even provides one of your requirements:

Given a source tree, that includes, say, jpg images, we can generate a view
filesystem which contains the same files resized to email size.

The github sources were last updated in 2018, so it might not be compatible
with your current installation. It also is probably not distributed as a
package so you may have to compile it.

This is an interesting approach, which I might try, thank you for sharing!

Over the years, many problems have been simplified by providing a web-based
interface. I don't know if Syncthing can retrieve a tree of files from an
http server, but if necessary, something like wget can do so as an
intermediate step.
It is not that difficult to set up an internal web server on a
PC.
There are lots of heavyweight web server solutions like apache and
nginx, but in fact you can create a simple web server in just a few
lines of code, and many such servers exist written in Perl, Python, etc.
The server will usually, by default, present a tree of files as a tree of
urls you can descend with your browser. Each directory needs to be
converted by the server into an "index.html" file with href links to the
files and subdirectories in the directory. Each file is typically just sent
as-is, prefixed with an http header derived from the mimetype of the file's
extension suffix. The server can, for example, add the header
Content-Type: audio/mpeg; when it sees a file with suffix .mp3.
However, the interesting part comes with cgi, the Common Gateway Interface.
You can get the web server to run a program when a given url is sent by the
browser. There is nothing to stop you running ImageMagick when your
server sees a url ending .jpg, or running ffmpeg when it sees .mp3.
And the cgi code does not have to be written in a special web programming
language like php.
An interesting example of this is bashttpd, A simple, configurable HTTP server written in bash.
This was last updated in 2015, but it still works. It is a single shell
script that you run from socat which is listening on a suitable local free
port such as 8080: (Obviously, this server is not secure and should only be run
locally)
socat TCP4-LISTEN:8080,bind=127.0.0.1,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:/path/to/bashttpd

By default it serves directories via the tree -H program which generates
an html index, and files are simply sent as-is. But you can easiy add a
function to the script to recognise a url pattern and do something
different. For example, add these bash commands to the start of the
configuration file, bashttpd.conf:
serve_jpg() {
   add_response_header "Content-Type" "image/gif"
   send_response 200 </dev/null
   convert "$2" -resize '50%' /tmp/myimage.gif
   cat /tmp/myimage.gif
   exit 0
}
on_uri_match '^/(.*\.jpg)$' serve_jpg

This will run function serve_jpg when a url ends .jpg, passing the url
converted to a filename. The script then uses
ImageMagick's convert to convert the file to gif format, and resize it
by 50%, before sending it back to the browser.
You could filter the tree -H output to replace all the filenames ending
.jpg by .gif, and so provide a "correct" renamed view of the filenames
as well.
